# post android to rails 4

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, post, image-uploading

i've been trying to make a multipart post to upload a photo, but i just can't figure out how to solve this. firstly, my server log:

```
Started POST "/ads" for 192.168.0.17 at 2014-06-19 12:11:07 -0300
 Processing by AdsController#create as HTML   Parameters:
 {"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001010beee0
 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/h1/ql7mfgwn2yd9yf5_t11fv4mm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140619-605-1yfs6sb>,
 @original_filename="IMG_20140619_121043.jpg",
 @content_type="application/octet-stream",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";
 filename=\"IMG_20140619_121043.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type:
 application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n">,
 "category_id"=>"1", "title"=>"jaba", "price"=>"01",
 "description"=>"nsna"} Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

 ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is
 empty: ad):   app/controllers/ads_controller.rb:82:in `ad_params'  
 app/controllers/ads_controller.rb:37:in `create'
```

i don't know why that ad param is empty! this is my android side code:

```
FileBody bin = new FileBody(mediaFile);

                MultipartEntityBuilder ad = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                ad.addPart("image", bin);
                ad.addTextBody("category_id", adCategory);
                ad.addTextBody("title", adTitle);
                ad.addTextBody("price", adPrice);
                ad.addTextBody("description", adDescription);



                httpPostRequest.setEntity(ad.build());


                HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPostRequest);
```

and this is my create method on the server side:

```
def create
    @ad = Ad.new(ad_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ad.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ad, notice: 'Ad was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ad }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @ad.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


def ad_params
 params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :price, :location, :description, :image, :category_id)
end
```

****edit*******

i think the ad param should be the json i get from post, but i don't know how to create that json including the image file. look what i've done so far:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("category_id", adCategory);
                json.put("title", adTitle);
                json.put("price", adPrice);
                json.put("description", adDescription);
                json.put("image", teste);
                StringEntity adParams = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                adParams.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                httpPostRequest.setEntity(adParams);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your prompt reply! would you tell me how do i do that please?

Comment: What was the name of the missing param? You have no `ad.addTextBody("ad", "xxxxxx")` for a sixth param i would think.

Comment: i think the ad param should be the json i get from post, but i don't know how to create that json including the image file. look what i've done so far:

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

json.put("category_id", adCategory);
json.put("title", adTitle);
json.put("price", adPrice);
json.put("description", adDescription);
//json.put("image", ?);
StringEntity adParams = new StringEntity(json.toString());
adParams.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
httpPostRequest.setEntity(adParams);
it works fine without json.put("image", ?);

Comment: Please do not place code in a comment. Its unreadable. Place it in your post.

Comment: this part is my problem: json.put("image", teste); i don't know how to place my image here

Comment: it is actually nothing, but i need it to be an image file i get from the camera and save as "mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");"

Comment: No. I don't believe you. Why should your image be wrapped in JSON? It was ok with addPart(). You still did not tell the name of the missing param. Did you remove all addTextBody()?

Comment: my problem is: i need to create an ad with title, price, description and image. so i get those strings and that image and upload to my server. when i build up the json without the image file, it works just fine. when i try to use a multipart post so i can add my image file, i get that error telling me my ad parameter (which should be my json) is missing. sombody told me i should nest my parameters, but i could NOT do it as well

Comment: btw, thanks for spending your time trying to help me!

Comment: Try to base64 encode the image. Then you can use it instead of teste.

Comment: ok, will do it and post the result here!